# Is it possible to invoke methods of a session bean directly after deployment?

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm using GlassFish. This is what I want to do. I have different ejb modules which can be deployed independently from each other. But I want to have one central ejb module where all the deployed modules have to register. This is because not all modules have to be deployed.

I thought the best way is if each ejb module contains a session bean (or what ever) with a specific method which will be immediately called after the module was deployed. But I found no such functionality. The whole process should happen after deployment because then a client can ask a session bean of the central ejb module which modules are registered at the moment.

I already tried the lifecycle functionality but there I have to create an own jar file which has to be placed in the lib directory of the application server which isn't really what I want. Furthermore if I call the register method of the central ejb module an exception will be thrown that this action is not allowed.

Does anybody know how I can manage this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you accomplish this by attempting to look them up in JNDI?  They won't be there if they are not deployed.  This is a registration and lookup mechanism, it just binds resources to names, but you can assume that if the name is not found it isn't deployed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is that I don't know the names of modules. Only the modules know the name of the one central module. By the way I noticed if this should work there also has to be a starting order which ensures that the central or basic module will be load as first one.